# Using pmatch for checking columns of a matrix into another

Tags: r, matrix, match

I have two matrices and I want to check which (column) vectors of the first one are also in the second one, and if so to get their index.

I tried to use `pmatch` but I have to tweak it a bit because it first convert the matrices into vector, see the MWE:

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(12), 3, 4)
x <- X[, c(2, 4)]

pm <- pmatch(x, X)
print(pm)
[1]  4  5  6 10 11 12

d1 <- dim(X)[1]
d2 <- length(pm)/d1
ind <- pmatch(x, X)[d1*c(1:d2)]/d1
print(ind)
[1] 2 4
```

`ind` is what I want, but I guess there might be prebuilt function to do it. And I'm also concerned with computational efficiency.

Comment: Will `x`'s columns, always, have exactly one matching column in `X`? Why are you not using `match` instead of `pmatch`?

Comment: you're right `pmatch` does not work is `x` as several duplicated columns, and I should have used `match`. Indeed I thought `match` only returned boolean like `%in%`

Answer (score 2):

We can loop over the columns of 'x' and use `==`

```
sapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function(i) which(!colSums(X != x[,i])))
#[1] 2 4
```

Comment: I did some `microbenchmarking` and interestingly `pmatch`is much slower (100 times) than `sapply(...`

Comment: @clemlaflemme  Another option is `paste`  `match(apply(x, 2, paste, collapse=" "), apply(X, 2, paste, collapse=" "))` it could be slower

Comment: much slower indeed